# `self_contained: false` causes greek font issue in DT

Tags: r, windows, fonts

When I set `self_contained: false` instead of `true`, Greek characters appear as you see in the picture. With `self_contained: true` everything is OK. Any ideas?

````
---
title: "self_contained issue in DT"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
    toc: no
---

## Εισαγωγή

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(DT)

table.no <- 0


reliability <- structure(list(Ομάδα = structure(c(8L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
1L), .Label = c("ΕΚΤΑΚΤΗ ΑΝΑΓΚΗ", "ΕΠΑΦΗ ΜΕ ΦΥΣΙΚΟΥΣ / ΧΗΜΙΚΟΥΣ ΠΑΡΑΓΟΝΤΕΣ", 
"ΕΡΓΟΤΑΞΙΑΚΑ ΓΡΑΦΕΙΑ", "ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΟ ΡΕΥΜΑ", "ΚΥΚΛΟΦΟΡΙΑ ΟΧΗΜΑΤΩΝ / ΜΗΧΑΝΗΜΑΤΩΝ / ΤΡΕΝΩΝ", 
"ΟΛΙΣΘΗΣΕΙΣ / ΠΤΩΣΕΙΣ", "ΣΥΝΘΗΚΕΣ ΕΡΓΑΣΙΑΣ", "ΣΥΝΟΛΟ"), class = "factor"), 
    α = c(0.933, 0.809, 0.916, 0.87, 0.88, 0.709, 0.626, 0.905
    ), ρ = c(0.966, 0.899, 0.957, 0.933, 0.938, 0.842, 0.791, 
    0.951)), .Names = c("Ομάδα", "α", "ρ"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")


datatable(reliability, class = 'cell-border stripe hover', caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
    style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
    paste0('Table ',(table.no <- table.no + 1),': '), htmltools::em('Συντελεστής α του Cronbach και εκτιμώμενος συντελεστής συσχέτισης ρ.')
  ))

```

sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253    LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] htmltools_0.2.6 tools_3.2.1     yaml_2.1.13     rmarkdown_0.7   knitr_1.10.5    digest_0.6.8
````

[image]

Comment: Both `true` and `false` works for me. My locale is `en_GB.UTF-8` on Linux. Try to change the locale. (I am not sure about the effectiveness on Windows).

Comment: Tried this `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` but nothing changed.

Comment: It might be Windows-specific. I cannot reproduce the issue on Linux, either. I'll test Windows tomorrow.

Comment: Might be a bug of rmarkdown or htmltools. Filed to https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/464